# MS Access Crosstab Query w/ Date Parameter Not Working Properly

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have a MS Access Table with the following information

DA Attendance

- Attendance ID (Key)
- Date
- DA
- Attendance Record (Dropdown with 6 options)
- Note

I am trying to create a cross tab query that will display the following:

[Query Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD5Kd.png)

I am able to get the crosstab query without any date parameters to work as intended. The picture above is how it looks. However, when I add the parameter I get the following error: "The expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be evaluated..." . I have a form in which the user inputs a specific day for which to create the query.

[Query Design 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtvYy.png)
[Query Design 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0yOZ.png)

Raw Data Example

| Attendance ID | DA | Date | Attendance Record | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 65 | 2021-09-16 | Present |  |
| 2 | 37 | 2021-09-16 | No Call No Show | No text response |
| 3 | 25 | 2021-09-16 | Tardy | 1155 AM arrival |
| 4 | 58 | 2021-09-16 | Present |  |

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![DA Attendance Form]![DA_Attendance_Date] DateTime;
TRANSFORM Count([DA Attendance].[Attendance ID]) AS [CountOfAttendance ID]
SELECT [DA Attendance].DA
FROM [DA Attendance]
WHERE ((([DA Attendance].Date)=[Forms]![DA Attendance Form]![DA_Attendance_Date]))
GROUP BY [DA Attendance].DA
PIVOT [DA Attendance].[Attendance Record];
```

Comment: It works for me. Edit question to show raw data as text table.

Comment: Raw data example has been added. In the actual table there are multiple dates but the table looks exactly as is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. MS Access is acting as the front end for a SQL Server database. The field "Date" was declared as type Date() in SQL Server which for whatever reason pulled as "Short Text" in Access. Edited the field type to DateTime() in SQL Server and it solved the issues when running the query.